# Remember filter method in grid after page refreshing using js(Asp.Net c# web application)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my project, filtering in gridview has been performed by designer team using javascript code.
How to make filters remember the filter method after page refreshing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#grdMain').dataTable( {
    stateSave: true
} );
```

} );

If I use above statements then it gives

> "cannot reinitialize datatable....."

error message.

Can anybody help me out for solving this issue?

Comment: I think "dataTable" is some plugin for jQuery. But which one? If you are able to control JS flow you can save and restore some custom information in own cookie.

Comment: Hi.........Maxim.....

Comment: Hi.........Maxim.....the above code statements uses localStorage & sessionStorage APIs for efficient storage of the data. It manges cookies on its own but the issue is when I write above statements it gives me above error msg.